# Program with license key specific to computer won't run over remote desktop connection

Tags: licensing, remote-desktop

I have a program (Minitab 16) that is licensed, registered, and activated on a computer on my network, and I need to be able to run that program via remote desktop.  I thought it would still run as it is still being used on that computer, but apparently it knows that I'm logged in remotely and will not run. Is there a way to do this? I know it is somewhat ambiguous, but I guess I'm wondering **how** the program knows I'm logged in remotely and how to stop it from knowing.

**Edit**: I have a single user license and the EULA states

> A.2 This Software may be loaded on only one computer and used by only one user at a time. If the computer on which this Software is loaded is attached to a network, this Software must not be accessible by any other user on such network.

As pointed out below, the EULA does not define computer/machine/user/licensee/etc, so its hard to tell whether I **should** be able to do this or not, but regardless, it seems that I can't; and so, I'll search for other methods of accomplishing a similar effect, and to best adhere to the license terms.

I have a single user license.

Comment: How to programmatically check for remote connections - that's a material for another question.

Comment: "How the program knows" and "how to stop it from knowing" are two very different questions.

Comment: Do you have a single-user or multi-user license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried VNC?

Comment: I haven't yet, but that was a suggestion from a co-worker as well. It is a customer machine, so it is not the ideal situation, but it is an option, if it works.

Comment: I assume that there is a single-user license. Who is the licensee? Your customer, or you?

Comment: @Tadeusz The EULA doesn't operate that way. A single-user license in this context appears to represent one simultaneous user is licensed - rather than one licensed user.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the check could be performed against Windows user impersonation. There's not enough useful information to speculate further, though.

Answer (score -1):

You are bound by the terms of the program license. If you believe that this usage does not constitute a breach of the license terms, then you should contact the vendors of that program.

We will not advise you about ways to break the law.

Comment: I'm not looking for ways to break the law, I'm looking for something like telling the program to look at the local registry and not the remote registry. This is for professional use.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not qualified to give legal advice. As far as I can ascertain, this represents a breach of the license terms: http://www.minitab.com/en-US/company/legal/license-agreements/minitab-eula.aspx

On the other hand, there's nothing wrong with telling someone how to perform an action which would invalidate a contract. Nor in telling them how to perform actions which could later be used for that purpose.

Comment: To be honest, it's a pretty crap EULA. They don't define 'computer' and 'user'. The EULA is pretty much indefensible.

Comment: Thanks @Rushyo that is what I was looking for. I'm assuming you are referring to this section 
A.2 This Software may be loaded on only one computer and used by only one user at a time. If the computer on which this Software is loaded is attached to a network, this Software must not be accessible by any other user on such network.
But its not another user if the I login with original user credentials just from another machine, right?

Comment: That's the thing. credentials != user != licensee != computer != machine != system != lots of other things. Without clarification there's no way to know what on earth they meant.

Comment: @roviuser: I am not a lawyer, but I'll just suggest that hacking remote-desktop detection code might breach C.4 (reverse-engineering).

Comment: @Tadeusz I imagine if he knew how to reverse-engineer it he'd have done it to find out already.

Comment: @Tadeusz:  We don't advise how to break the law.  How sure are you that this would constitute breaking the law in roviuser's jurisdiction?  Is what he's trying to do definitely prohibited by any agreement he may have with the vendor?  Are you sure this would violate any law?  (Even the US's infamous DMCA has exceptions that may apply in this case.)  We don't generally advise how to do unethical things either, but this looks to me like a guy trying to use paid-for software in a convenient way, nothing worse.